# angularjs input mapped to array element

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm new in Angularjs and I'm developing a kind of shopping cart
I have and array:

```
 $scope.products = [
{id: '141', name: 'Apple', qty:0}, 
{id: '223', name: 'Orange', qty:0},
{id: '398', name: 'Banana', qty:0}];
```

By design limitation  I need to do something like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="products[productID].qty"/>
```

(I can't use array element index I know it works.)

I've tried also with

```
ng-model="(p in products | filter: {id:'223'}).qty"
```

But I couldn't make it work

Please Could you help me ??

I will explain my shopping cart
Let imagine that I need a table in the columns the sizes:s,m,l, xl
in the rows models, but there are models that are manufactured in all sizes so I will have an input in every cell, but there are some that are only in l and xl and other in s and m 
So I will have a table with some empty cells.
I know I can have a table that works as metadata where I can define columns, rows and the mapping and then develop a directive. My idea is design the table in HTML and assign to each cell the productID

Comment: I don't get it. You need to show one item from the `products` array? How do you know which one to show?

Comment: Yes I have to map one Item from the products array to an input and I need to map the product that has id=223

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're going to have to select the id out from the array so in your directive/controller write something like this:

```
$scope.getProduct = function(id) {
  var product;
  angular.forEach($scope.products, function(p) {
    if(p.id === id) {
      product = p;
    }
  });
  return product;
};
```

Then:

```
$scope.selectedProduct = $scope.getProduct('223');
```

Then in your html:

```
<input ng-model="selectedProduct.qty"/>
```

**EDIT:** I have no idea if this is what you're talking about but here goes. (You do know about `ngRepeat` right?):

```
<table>
  <thead>... stuff</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
      <td ng-bind="product.id"></td>
      <!-- bind other stuff here -->
      <td>
        <input ng-model="product.qty"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I will explain my shopping cart

Comment: I've edited my question and I add the description of my shopping cart